# How can I use XLOOKUP (or similar) to return multiple different return values from identical lookup values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

if this should be asked elsewhere please let me know.

Is there a way for me to use XLOOKUP to return multiple different return values for identical lookup values?

For example, in a table like the one shown below, I would want to return A, B, C, D for lookup value 1. Currently I can only get it to return one of the values and just repeat it until moving on to the next lookup value.

| Lookup | Return |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | D |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what FILTER is for:

```
=FILTER(B:B,A:A=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I'll have to do things a little differently than I was expecting, but I guess that's what this whole process is about. I appreciate the help!

Comment: What a boss. Very nice answer. In addition if you dont have office 365, have a google for n'th vlookup, like this https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-vlookup